# Joomla facebook Connect

Tags: joomla, facebook

Is there a non-commercial component for [joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) to connect to [facebook](http://www.facebook.com/) , (registration and login ) ?

I am trying to this for both  sites : [www.shusar.net](http://www.shusar.net/) and [www.gositelebanon.com](http://www.gositelebanon.com)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this one 
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/authentication-cloud-based/16350

if this link doesn't works download it from here http://saaraan.com/index.php/joomla-facebook-graph-connect